# HTML script .load preventing responsive elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gumby-framework

I'm using the `gumby framework` from [here](http://gumbyframework.com/) and everything seems to be going well. I would like to implement a mobile navigation list (where the links are grouped under a single button as detailed [here](http://gumbyframework.com/docs/ui-kit/#!/navigation)).

This works fine with a normal HTML page, but as I have multiple pages with the same header (nav bar)/footer, I decided to put all the HTML for those in separate files, and load them with a script:

```
<script>
    // load navigation/footer
    $(function () {
        $("#navigation").load("html/nav.html");
        $("#footer").load("html/footer.html");
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I do this, my mobile navigation list does **not** work (as if the mobile nav bar is being initialized, then the document loads the HTML resulting in no hooks). I hope there's a simple fix for this. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

> preventing responsive elements

Do you mean, event handlers and the like are not bound to the new HTML that has been loaded ?

---

One way is to set delegated event handlers

```
$(document).on('click','.mylaterloadedanchors', function() { ...
```

But this is quite overkill to have too many of these.

---

Another, looking into controlling the bindings into a function that you can call after templates/DOM partials have loaded.

- load templates
- set handlers of the template.

Say,

```
var app = function() { 

    .. list all listeners etc
    };

/* load templates using the callback jq provides for .load() 
   and trigger the app containing the listeners*/

$('#navigation').load('html/nav.html', app);
```

---

Another way is to have your `nav.html` js bindings src'd from the nav.html page itself.

Not a bad idea when managing 'views' - eg

`nav.html` ships with `nav.js` etc ..

*views* with *viewmodels* and *viewbindings*

Comment: Moving the `<script src="../..js"/>` to the top of the `nav.html` file worked. Now I can remove them all from the other HTML pages which should clean it up a little more! Thanks :)